# Verbs: Non finite forms

Tags: grammar

Is "swimming" a participle in 'I love swimming'? I think it is participle as it defines the noun 'I' in the above sentence.

Comment: _Swimming_ is a participle verb form (the present active participle form, to be precise). If you want to call it a participle in _I love swimming_ you will find people to agree with you; but you'll find others disagreeing. You seem to think that "participle" describes some standard thing in English; no doubt you were taught this. Unfortunately, it's not true. There are a lot of different ways to use the _-ing_ form, and "participle" does not have enough precise meaning to describe them. Personally, I would call _swimming_ in that sentence a noun. Though it could be a gerund.

Comment: Quirk et al (ACGEL) would probably say / have said it's towards the nounal end of the noun - verb continuum of _ing_-forms, without actually having made it to true nounness (contrast 'painting' in 'She loves my new painting'). I tend to agree. The CGEL fans would want you to call it a 'gerund-participle'. Neither school would accept it as a 'participle'.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is *mildly ambiguous* as is, and can be interpreted in one of two possible ways.  See John Lawler's and Edwin Ashworth's comments under your question from Sept. 28, 2016:

1. "Swimming" can be a [**verbal noun**](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/verbal_nouns.htm) describing a leisure activity.  It could very well be replaced with another noun like *tennis* or *volleyball* while keeping the rest of the sentence identical.
2. "Swimming" could also be a **gerund**.  This is a non-finite verb form which is *used as a noun*, and for any given tense/voice combo*, will *always look identical* to the participle form.  *However*, the gerund form is a substantive, not a modifier (this means it's used as noun, as opposed to as an adjective/adverb).  You can only tell the difference between these two forms from the context.

A sentence which is unambiguously an instance of 1. (verbal noun) would be, "Students at Example High School must sign up for either swimming or volleyball for PE."  *--Here, 'swimming' is more clearly a verbal noun because it is in parallel with another 'normal' noun (volleyball).*

A sentence which is unambiguously an instance of 2. (gerund) would be, "Students at Example High School excel at swimming fast and studying hard."  *--Here, 'swimming' *must* be a gerund because it is clearly referring to the *action* and not to the sport/recreational activity.  An attempt to substitute a 'normal' noun here would result in nonsense:  "Students at Example High School excel at volleyball fast and studying hard" just doesn't work!*

So, which one of the two possibilities most accurately describes the sentence from your question ("I love swimming") depends on *what exactly* it is you love:  'swimming' as an *activity*, or 'swimming' as an *action*.

- **Tense:** *present*, *perfect* etc.; **voice:** *active* or *passive*

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> *Swimming* is a participle verb form (the present active participle form, to be precise). If you want to call it a participle in *I love swimming* you will find people to agree with you; but you'll find others disagreeing. You seem to think that "participle" describes some standard thing in English; no doubt you were taught this. Unfortunately, it's not true. There are a lot of different ways to use the *-ing* form, and "participle" does not have enough precise meaning to describe them. Personally, I would call *swimming* in that sentence a noun. Though it could be a gerund.